# Maven child module does not exist

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven. I checked out from SVN a project from a customer with the following structure:

```
projectName
|--> pom.xml
|--> jetty-wrapper
     |--> pom.xml
     |--> bin
          |--> pom.xml
|--> projectName-common
     |--> pom.xml
     |--> bin
          |--> pom.xml
|--> projectName-war
     |--> bin
          |--> pom.xml
```

the pom.xml right below 'projectName` (the pom at the top) is building the three modules

```
<modules>
    <module>projectName-common</module>
    <module>projectName-war</module>
    <module>jetty-wrapper</module>
</modules>
```

But when executing `mvn clean install` from folder `projectName`it gives the following error

```
Child module [...]projectName\projectName-war\pom.xml of [...]projectName\pom.xml does not exist
```

The question is: Should there be a pom.xml right below `projectName-war`just like with the rest of the modules that my customer may have forgotten to commit to SVN?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The question is: Should there be a pom.xml right below projectName-war

Simply put **yes**.

You have already figured out the trick, and since you haven't provided a project descriptor aka *pom.xml* to maven, it won't be able to call the *projectName-war* a valid child module.

There must absolutely be a *pom.xml* file under *projectName-war*, and it must have an artifact id that matches the one under the parent declaring the module, i.e.

```
<artifactId>projectName-war</artifactId>
```

Answer (score 37):

```
Child module [...]projectName\projectName-war\pom.xml of [...]projectName\pom.xml does not exist
```

If you are getting the above error when using mvn install from command line (the same pom may work in eclipse) you have to change your pom.xml little

Instead of the below:

```
<modules>
        <module>../my-util</module>
        <module>../my-server</module>           
</modules>
```

Follow the below (enclose in a profilers):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <modules>
            <module>../my-util</module>
            <module>../my-server</module>           
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: This is what fixed my problem. Wasted more than an hour looking at other places. Also it would have been nice to have an explanation.

Comment: After enclosing the modules in profiles the error message disappeared but the build ignored the modules completely. It did not achive the desired effect to build the modules.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem as Jozsef Frigo, it builds but ignores modules. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 5):

This issue usually comes when you copy and paste the child projects.
For example, We have individual child projects as below

```
<artifactId>business-layer</artifactId> with project name as business-layer
<artifactId>service-layer</artifactId> with project name as **xyz**-layer
<modules>
        <module>business-layer</module>
        <module>**service-layer**</module>
</modules>
```

You project name during the initial build should be same as the module name. This need not require the  tag to be added as the purpose of profiles tag is to trigger builds with specific actions

Comment: exactly what happened in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this issue if you do have the pom.xml at the right location but it has errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I renamed some modules via ***IntelliJ***:

I managed to fix this by doing the following action:

Right click on each module's ***pom.xml*** then from the appearing list click on "`Add as Maven Module`"