# how to compile and build WAR before creating an EAR

Tags: java, maven

Using Maven I am first running the WAR build to generate the WAR file and store in local repository.
I then run the maven build to create the EAR file.

So everytime I want to deploy and test I have to do 2 builds from eclipse.
I am using maven , eclipse .

This project is in early stages of development so going the Jenkins route is premature. 
is there a way that when I run the EAR build - it will FIRST build the war rather than use the one in local repository ?

If this is possible I save some time by a single click I get two builds done rather than do them manually.

Comment: Use a parent pom project, and have both the war and the ear be modules of the pom (with the war coming first). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990664/how-to-build-an-ear-project-with-ejb-and-war-using-maven?rq=1) for example

Comment: thanks for the quick response - so having them as modules would it force a recompile and build of the WAR before it gets bundled as EAR ?

Comment: Yes. You'll build one project, the parent, and modules will be built as part of that... and the ear will  pick up the war just built.

Comment: ok cool thanks will take a look - could you post your comment as an answer - once I have it tested - would accept your answer and thank you.

Comment: ok yes this works with a parent pom  but only tweak I had to do was not specify them as modules ( since my ear and war maven projects were in a different location on disk ) so specified a relative path to the two projects in <profile> section. I referred to this answer here ( satish.kanikaram ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021141/maven-child-module-does-not-exist